# O Git tem o recurso que subversion tinha keyword substitution ou algo parecido?

Tags: git

Quando eu trabalhava com cvs e Subversion eu me lembro de um recurso onde colocávamos algumas anotações nos arquivos e cada vez que fazíamos um *commit* esses dados eram atualizados. Em geral os dados se referiam a data, autor e número do *commit*. Era algo parecido com o exemplo abaixo

```
/*
 *   $Author: joazinho $
 *   $Rev: 153 $
 *   $LastChangedDate: 2016-04-15 17:32:15 -0300 (Fri, 15 Apr 2016) $
 */
```

No Git algo parecido para eu pegar o branch / tag, hash ou etc... que seja nativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diretamente não tem não. Mas é possível fazer *scripts* que façam isto por você.

Ele disponibiliza [atributos](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes) que podem ser usados no seu *script*.

Exemplo:

```
MYVERSION = '1.090'
## Call script to do updateVersion from .git/hooks/pre-commit
def updateVersion
  # We add 1 because the next commit is probably one more - though this is a race
  commits = %x[git log #{$0} | grep '^commit ' | wc -l].to_i + 1
  vers = "1.%0.3d" % commits

  t = File.read($0)
  t.gsub!(/^MYVERSION = '(.*)'$/, "MYVERSION = '#{vers}'")
  bak = $0+'.bak'
  File.open(bak,'w') { |f| f.puts t }
  perm = File.stat($0).mode & 0xfff
  File.rename(bak,$0)
  File.chmod(perm,$0)
  exit
end
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13353303/221800).

[Mais exemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17242693/221800).

> The whole notion of keyword substitution is just totally idiotic. It's trivial to do "outside" of the actual content tracking, if you want to have it when doing release trees as tar-balls etc.
>
> -- Linus Tovards